# Cannot connect to SQL Server from python with a specific user

Tags: python, sql-server

I have to users to connect to a SQL Server. On the server, I need to read from SQL Server into python and write from python to SQL Server.

When I login with one one the users, everything goes fine with connection, whether I use Windows authentication or SQL Server authentication, with this code:

SQL Server authentication:

```
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://myservername/mydatabasename/driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?Trusted_Connection = no/UID = sa/PWD = mypassword")
conn = engine.connect()
df.to_sql(name = 'TestTable1', schema='dbo', con = conn)
```

Windows authentication:

```
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://myservername/mydatabasename/driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?Trusted_Connection = yes")
conn = engine.connect()
df.to_sql(name = 'TestTable1', schema='dbo', con = conn)
```

but with another user, I got this error:

> Data source name too long State:IM010,Native:0,Origin:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]

Does this error do something with the other user?

Comment: Just to be sure: did you tested connectivity for this user thru `sqlcmd`?

Answer (score 0):

For every login SQL Server needs credentials setup for Windows authentication or SQL Server authentication. You can test the credentials using SSMS before you use them in the Python program.

Comment: I can login to SSMS with SQL Server credentials without any problem. The thing however, is that the password which I login into server is different from the password which I loging into SSMS with sa. Might that be the problem?